# Why the Xunit CollectionDefinition Not Working with Class Library in .NET 6 Web App?

Tags: c#, web-applications, .net-6.0, xunit.net

When developing a web app, quite often we need to do unit testing against objects in class libraries. I run into the problem when trying to use Xunit "CollectionDefinition" feature to share content between multiple test cases. (see details in following sections)

**TEST ENVIRONMENT**

- Windows 11 and Visula Studio 2022 community edition
- .NET 6 Web App "XunitDemo" with a .NET 6 Class Library "DataHelper"
- Packages:
  Xunit 2.4.2
  Xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.4.3

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:**

In order to test sharing content between following test cases, I wrote test code with following components

1. The class to be tested: **DataHelper.TextHelper** (see code segment 1)
2. Test project:  **DataHelperTests**
3. In test project, created the "fixture" object **TextHelperFixture** (see code segment 2)
4. In test project, Created the xunit **CollectionDefinition** (see code segment 3)
5. To make sure the TextHelperFixture works correctly, I setup first test case: **TextHelperFixtureTest** (see code segment 4)
6. To test the content sharing between multiple test cases, I setup 2 separate test cases: **CollectionDefTest1** & **CollectionDefTest2** with **[Collection(....)]** attribute. Each has 1 test method (see code segments 5 and 6)

**Testing Steps:**

1. To verify the "fixture" object actually works, I run **TextHelperFixtureTest** and it passed with no error.
2. To test the "CollectionDefinition", I tried to execute first test method:  CollectDefTest1.CollDefTest1. It failed with following error:

```
﻿ DataHelperTests.CollectionDefTest1.CollDefTest1
 Source: CollectionDefTest1.cs line 15
 Duration:1 ms

  Message: The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: TextHelperFixture fixture
```

3. When running second test with CollectionDefTest2.CollDefTest2, the similar error occurred:

```
﻿ DataHelperTests.CollectionDefTest2.CollDefTest1
 Source: CollectionDefTest2.cs line 16
 Duration: 1 ms

 Message: The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: TextHelperFixture thFixture
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. The test result of "TextHelperFixtureTest" showed that the "Fixture" object is working fine when it was directly instantiated inside of the test case. Why using the "CollectionDefinition" caused the error of unable to find the "Fixture" class?
2. I thought that it was possible the CollectionDefinition won't work with class library.  I actually setup a console app with class library, The "CollectionDefinition" was working fine there. Why this problem occurs when the main project is a .NET 6 web app?

It will be greatly appreciated if anyone has suggestions and troubleshooting tips.

**TEST CODE SEGMENTS**

------ Code Segment 1: Class in library to be Tested ------

```
namespace DataHelper
{
    public class TextHelper
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public TextHelper() { }

        public TextHelper (string fn, string ln)
        {
            FirstName = fn;
            LastName = ln;
        }

        public string GetFullName()
        {
            return $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
        }
    }
}
```

------ Code Segment 2:  "Fixture" object in test project ------

```
using System;

namespace DataHelperTests
{
    public class TextHelperFixture: IDisposable
    {
        public string FullName { get; private set; }

        public TextHelperFixture()
        {
            TextHelper st = new TextHelper("Jason", "Williams");
            FullName = st.GetFullName();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

------ Code Segment 3: CollectionDefinition in Test project ------

```
using Xunit;

namespace DataHelperTests
{
    [Collection("TextHelper Collection")]
    public class TextHelperFixtureCollection : ICollectionFixture<TextHelperFixture> { }
}
```

------ Code Segment 4:  Test case to verify "fixture" object ------

```
using Xunit;

namespace DataHelperTests
{
    public class TextHelperFixtureTest
    {
        private TextHelperFixture _fxt;
        public TextHelperFixtureTest()
        {
            _fxt = new TextHelperFixture();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void FixtureTest()
        {
            Assert.NotNull(_fxt.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

------ Code Segment 5:  first test utilizes the Collection ------

```
using Xunit;

namespace DataHelperTests
{
    [Collection("TextHelper Collection")]
    public class CollectionDefTest1
    {
        private TextHelperFixture _fixture;
        public CollectionDefTest1(TextHelperFixture fixture)
        {
            _fixture = fixture;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void CollDefTest1()
        {
            string result = _fixture.FullName;
            Assert.Contains("Jason", result);
        }
    }
}
```

------ Code Segment 6: second test case that ultilizes the collection ------

```
using Xunit;

namespace DataHelperTests
{
    [Collection("TextHelper Collection")]
    public class CollectionDefTest2
    {
        private TextHelperFixture _fixture;
            
        public CollectionDefTest2(TextHelperFixture thFixture)
        {
            _fixture = thFixture;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void CollDefTest1()
        {
            Assert.NotNull(_fixture.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Under `Code Segment 3: CollectionDefinition in Test project -` you are using `Collection`, not `CollectionDefinition`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake I made in the test code.  I corrected in Code sample 3 and the tests are working now.

Comment: @ruben-bartelink:  please make your comments as the answer to the question so that I can mark it as "resolved"?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done 99% of it perfectly (it's a pleasure to answer a question where someone has clearly taken the time to surface as much as possible in textbook fashion like here) - just a typo/mistake under

> **Code Segment 3: CollectionDefinition in Test project**

you are using the `[Collection]` attribute as one correctly would on the Test Class, but you meant `[CollectionDefinition]`, which is the counterpart for the definition bit...

(Putting this in long form for future readers - you obviously had it all sorted but just typo'd in this instance)